# Unterminated &lt;html:select tag - JSP threw exception

Tags: html

I am getting the `Unterminated &lt;html:select tag`  error when I deployed my application on Tomcat.

Snippet of my code look like this

```
   <TD><SPAN class=modulecontent>     

            <html:select property="countryName"  size="1" tabindex="6" styleClass="modulecontent" value="<%=pdmReq.getCountryName()%>" onchange="javascript:makeDefault(this,this.form.segment);"> 
              <html:option value="0">--Please Select--</html:option>
                <%
                    for (int index=0; index<countryList.size(); index++)
                    {
                %>
                <html:option value="<%=(String)((ArrayList)countryList.get(index)).get(0) %>" > <%=((ArrayList)countryList.get(index)).get(0) %></html:option>
                <%      
                    }
                %>
            </html:select>
                </SPAN></TD>
```

second line i.e `<html:select property="countryName"  size="1" tabindex="6" styleClass="modulecontent" value="<%=pdmReq.getCountryName()%>" onchange="javascript:makeDefault(this,this.form.segment);">`
  is generating the error.

I tried some googling but still facing the issue. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to reproduce the exception with the code above but it worked fine for me on my Tomcat 7 server with using a simple Struts app.

What I would suggest is to start to eliminate possible culprits to the exception.  That way you can at least know what is specifically causing the exception for you.  For example, start by removing the onchange attribute and its value.  If you still see the exception then move on to the value attribute, change the expression in there to be just a simple string value...something like value="test".

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not an answer it is a comment at best

Comment: Yes I knew it wasn't a definite answer, but I could not comment on the original question.  I spent some significant time trying to determine what was wrong so I felt I would add an answer to try to narrow down the cause.